# How to replicate the example navigation drawer from Android Docs?

Tags: android, listview, navigation, drawer

[For example, please view this image from the Android Developers site.](http://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_drawer_holo_dark_light.png)

Basically, I want to replicate this navigation drawer, currently I have it all except the sub items (Option 1, Option 2, in the example). There is no documentation on how to get this on the developers site. This is what I have currently:

- MainActivity.java: http://pastebin.com/iNXW00ex
- SeparatedListAdapter.java: http://pastebin.com/fESuvEVi
- MainActivity.xml: http://pastebin.com/gg4JANwh
- Drawer Item/Header.xml: http://pastebin.com/WzvPXQYm

That's all I think is needed. I'm aware that typically a expandable list view is used for the child items, though I'm unsure how to combine that with the current separated list adapter so I can still get titles.

Thanks, David.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of third party libs for sliding menus.
Why not use one of them instead of trying to recreate Android's?

For example:
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the Navigation Drawer tutorial in the Android docs?
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Uses classes in the support library to make implementing the nav drawer pretty straightforward.